# MySQL get max value per group joined on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, max, left-join, grouping

I found many answers to other similar queries, but none of them fit my requirements, hence the question.

First, the data:

```
orderid    type    year    change
1111       1       2018    333
1111       2       2018    4652
1111       1       2019    3645
1111       3       2019    444
2222       1       2018    6451
```

there's a joined key on columns orderid, type and year. So each order can have one entry per year for a certain type.

Now, the desired result (option 1):

```
orderid    type    year    change
1111       2       2018    4652
1111       1       2019    3645
```

What I am looking for is the max 'change' value for a given order per year. Type doesn't matter. '1111' is the sample order passed to the query.

And if the first challenge can be improved further, ideally I would like to receive the sum of the changes from the answer above. So the ideal results should look like this (option 2):

```
orderid    change
1111       8297
```

I have not attempted to get the second answer yet, which technically should be an easy wrap of an additional query over the results to sum the change columns returned. But what I've tried so far for the first question (and to add - without success) is this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
   LEFT JOIN table1 t2
   ON t1.orderid = t2.orderid AND t1.year = t2.year AND t1.change > t2.change
WHERE t2.change IS NULL
AND t1.orderid = '1111'
```

What this query returns is not entirely desired result where one max value is correct, but the other is not:

```
orderid    type    year    change
1111       1       2018    333
1111       1       2019    3645
```

Here it is. Now who would like to save my Friday night?

Help is always much appreciated!

Update 1:
I'm including an sqlfiddle with all of the above:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbb963/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQLFiddle doesn't work for two reasons. Firstly, and most importantly, you declared your `change` values as `VARCHAR` instead of `INT`. As a result, MySQL thinks that `444` > `3645`. Secondly, the `JOIN` condition should be `t1.change < t2.change`, not `t1.change > t2.change`. See the [updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b302a/3), which gives your desired results:

```
orderid     type    year    change
1111        2       2018    4652
1111        1       2019    3645
```

If the field has to remain a `VARCHAR`, you need to change your `JOIN` condition to

```
CAST(t1.change AS UNSIGNED) < CAST(t2.change AS UNSIGNED)
```

To get the SUM of the changes, simply use your query as a subquery, `SUM` change and `GROUP BY orderid`:

```
SELECT orderid, SUM(`change`) AS total_change
FROM (SELECT t1.*
      FROM table1 t1
      LEFT JOIN table1 t2
          ON t1.orderid = t2.orderid AND t1.year = t2.year AND t1.change < t2.change
      WHERE t2.change IS NULL AND t1.orderid = '1111') t
GROUP BY orderid
```

Output:

```
orderid     total_change
1111        8297
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b302a/6)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `VARCHAR` type when you are trying ti compare values.

So you need either `CAST` values when compare or [change your schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c40fc2c/1).

```
 ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY COLUMN `change` INT;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2786a/6

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
ON t1.orderid = t2.orderid 
   AND t1.year = t2.year 
   AND CAST(t1.change  AS UNSIGNED)  < CAST(t2.change AS UNSIGNED)
WHERE t2.change IS NULL
AND t1.orderid = '1111';

SELECT t1.*
FROM table2 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.orderid = t2.orderid 
   AND t1.year = t2.year 
   AND t1.change < t2.change
WHERE t2.change IS NULL
AND t1.orderid = '1111'
```

Comment: thank a lot for your input! The answer before yours came first, so I have to give the 'tick' to it.